# TypeError while doing fuzzy matching

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, fuzzywuzzy

I am getting a TypeError while doing fuzzy matching between 2 columns in 2 different dataframes. I have already taken care of nan's and also converted the datatype to string but it still fails. Also I'm not able to figure out which value is causing this error. I have already tried doing a match one by one by using for loop, but then the code never fails. Also, I dont want to use a for loop for this.

The error message is: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

The code is:

```
a = df1['ColAddress1'].dropna()  
b = df2['ColAddress2'].dropna()
match = process.extractOne(a, b, scorer=fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio)
```

I cannot share the data but it contains 4 type of chars:
alphabets [a-zA-Z], numbers, dash(-) and square brackets ([])

Anyone has any idea how can I resolve this.

Comment: We dont have any idea of what your data is. how can someone help solve the issue :)

Comment: It expects strings, but you are sending it `Series` Yes the values in the Series are probably strings, but that function does not work on a Series vs a Series. You need to iterate over all the pairs of string values within the Series.

Comment: @ALollz The link I used as a reference to code fuzzywuzzy has df1['ColAddress1'].dropna().values. My bad. thanks!

Comment: Updated my code for a better alternative to what you are doing.

Comment: Do check and let me know incase of any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Better alternative to your goal

Complete code for getting best match between 2 lists/series of strings -

1. Use `itertools` for getting combinations of a and b lists/series.
2. Use the scorer from `Fuzz directly on each combination.
3. Use `np.argmax` to get index of the highest score
4. Fetch the tuple with the 2 strings that have the best match.

```
import itertools
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import numpy as np

a = ['hi','there']  
b = ['hello','their']

scores = [fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio(i, j) for i,j in itertools.product(a,b)]
list(itertools.product(a,b))[np.argmax(scores)]
```

```
('there', 'their')
```

---

### Addressing the issue

The `process.extractOne` expects a `query` and `choices`. It returns the best match for the query from the choices.

`Query` is a string and `Choices` are the list/Series of strings you want to compare. Currently, you are passing it 2 Series. Instead use a loop over one of the Series to get best matches with the `Choices` from the other.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

a = ['hi','there']  
b = ['hello','their']
match = [(i,*process.extractOne(i, b, scorer=fuzz.partial_token_sort_ratio)) for i in a]
match
```

```
[('hi', 'hello', 50), ('there', 'their', 80)] #query, bestchoice, score
```

If you want the max tuple from this list, just use -

```
import numpy as np
match[np.argmax([i[2] for i in match])]
```

```
('there', 'their', 80)
```